# parsing a line in c with strtok for a shell

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying to parse a line for my own bash and I am using strtok and I find that strtok(line,"|") and strtok(line,"||") return the same answer.I don't understand how work strtok.So I can't differentiate between a pipe (|) and an or (||).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please look up the `man` page for `strtok`.  The `strtok` function looks for only one character, not a string.  Specifically it looks for _any_ character that is given in the string.

Comment: Hi dav1d0! Parsers in the real world face the same problem, you have to have some sort of look-ahead. I'd suggest peeking at the next character in the string and then deciding if you've got an OR or a PIPE. I don't think this approach is possible with strtok.

Comment: While you are reading the manual, also take a look at `strstr()` , `strchr()` , `strspn()` and `strcspn()`.